# Change div content with simple javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

how it possibly to change the right div content upon click on the left menu without reloading the page with only simple javascript code, not jquery tabbed plugins

http://postimg.org/image/sh7emxdlb/
HTML:

```
<div class="left">
    <ul>
        <li class="headerline1">Headline1</li>
        <li class="headerline2">Headline2</li>
        <li class="headerline3">Headline3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="header1">
    <h3> Headline1 </h3>
    <br/>
     <p>Content here...</p>
</div>
<div class="header2">
    <h3> Headline2 </h3>
     <br/>
     <p>Content here...</p>
</div>
<div class="header3">
    <h3> Headline3 </h3>
     <br/>
    <p>Content here...</p>
</div>
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated,

thanks

Comment: Ajax request will do the job

Comment: Please post your code here and explain the problem you are having more clearly

Comment: jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/Lbwoyw7y, the righ content wil show depending on the left menu, for exampe if someone click headline1 on the left the right div is show the headline 1 content, and so on @neelsg

Comment: I meant that you should post your code in the question (Edit it). The idea for this site is that your question and the answers for it could be useful to future visitors with the same issue. If you only post a link and that link becomes broken, the question you ask is meaningless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code. It may be helpful for you.

**[Live Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/9t249esr/)**

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="left">
    <ul>
        <li class="headerline1">Headline1</li>
        <li class="headerline2">Headline2</li>
        <li class="headerline3">Headline3</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<div class="header1">
    <h3> Headline1 </h3>
    <br/>
     <p>Content here...</p>
</div>
<div class="header2">
    <h3> Headline2 </h3>
     <br/>
     <p>Content here...</p>
</div>
<div class="header3">
    <h3> Headline3 </h3>
     <br/>
    <p>Content here...</p>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.left
{
    height:500px;
    width:250px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
ul li 
{
    list-style-type:none;
}
.header1, .header2, .header3
{
    display:none;
    height:500px;
    width:700px;


}
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$(".headerline1").click(function () {
        $(".header1").show();
        $(".header2").hide();
        $(".header3").hide();
    });
    $(".headerline2").click(function () {
            $(".header2").show();
            $(".header1").hide();
            $(".header3").hide();
        });

    $(".headerline3").click(function () {
            $(".header3").show();
            $(".header1").hide();
            $(".header2").hide();
        });
```

Comment: hi thank for the fiddle, unfortunately is not working yet, http://jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/Lbwoyw7y/ @singh

Comment: Try again i updated code.

Comment: Updated to http://jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/9t249esr/, Thanks @singh

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
document.getElementByID('rightDiv').innerHTML = "<h1>title</h1><div>content goes here</div>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [the Pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) named `:target`. No script.
And this is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7a40khjw/).

Comment: But there is a issue that when you load the page firstly, the left menu is invisibility and I haven't found the way to solve it.